# How to show correct records based on column from select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
|VALUE                                  |OSP_ID       |STYA_ID      |ESTPT_ID                               |DISCOUNT                               |SERO_ID      |ATTR_NUMBER                            |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|-------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|-------------|---------------------------------------|
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1812                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1812                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1916                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1916                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1987                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1987                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2027                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2027                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2028                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2028                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2029                                   |30                                     |3933326      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2029                                   |30                                     |3933327      |1                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1812                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1916                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |1987                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2027                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2028                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
|1                                      |619771       |34659        |2029                                   |40                                     |3933327      |2                                      |
```

I need to add check on each select has own `attr_number`. Based on this column i need to return records.

If records `exists` with `attr_number = 2`, then i should get records only those records.

If records `do not exists` with `attr_number = 2`, then i should get records only where `attr_number = 1`.

I was trying to play around to solve my issue and you can see commended lines(where is `left join` and `soi.value IS NULL`), but it's not working as i described. He is not checking if records exists.

Yes, we should use `union` to remove duplicate rows.

This select is used in `left outer join`.

``

Comment: this is not a complete query -- you don't have the outer select statement or from line

Comment: query doesn't show any reference to attr_number. please post the complete query

Comment: Sorry, i have forgot to add them here. Now all is fixed.

`left outer join` is just as informative point. In general this select returns me this data. http://prntscr.com/rahdvn

Answer (score 1):

ok now that you edited the question I understand... here is how I would do it using CTEs

```
WITH att2 AS
(
  SELECT soi.value, srv.osp_id, soi.stya_id, eoax.estpt_id, eoax.discount, int_sero.id AS sero_id, 2 as attr_number 
  FROM srv_obj_attr_intermediate soi
  JOIN estpt_objt_attr_xref eoax ON eoax.interest_rate = 1
  JOIN attribute_types attl ON attl.id = eoax.attr_id
  JOIN object_attribute_type_links oatl ON oatl.attr_id = attl.id
  JOIN service_type_attributes sta ON sta.objt_attr_id = oatl.id
  JOIN service_objects int_sero ON int_sero.id = soi.sero_id
  JOIN services srv ON srv.id = int_sero.srv_id
  JOIN order_event_types oet ON oet.code = 'CALC_INTERMEDIATE_ESTP'
  WHERE eoax.ordet_id = oet.id AND eoax.objt_attr_id = sta.objt_attr_id
    AND soi.stya_id = sta.id AND soi.value = 1
), att1 AS
(
  SELECT soa.value, srv.osp_id, soa.stya_id, eoax.estpt_id, eoax.discount, int_sero.id AS sero_id, 1 as attr_number
  FROM srv_obj_attributes soa
  JOIN estpt_objt_attr_xref eoax ON eoax.interest_rate = 1
  JOIN attribute_types attl ON attl.id = eoax.attr_id
  JOIN object_attribute_type_links oatl ON oatl.attr_id = attl.id
  JOIN service_type_attributes sta ON sta.objt_attr_id = oatl.id
  --LEFT JOIN srv_obj_attr_intermediate soi ON soi.stya_id = sta.id
        --AND soi.value = 1
  JOIN service_objects int_sero ON int_sero.id = soa.sero_id
  JOIN services srv ON srv.id = int_sero.srv_id
  JOIN order_event_types oet ON oet.code = 'CALC_INITIAL_ESTP'
  WHERE eoax.ordet_id = oet.id AND eoax.objt_attr_id = sta.objt_attr_id
    AND soa.stya_id = sta.id AND soa.value = 1 --AND soi.value IS NULL
), base AS
(
  SELECT estpt_id, sero_id, osp_id,
         COALESCE(att1,att2) as source
  FROM (
    SELECT estpt_id, sero_id, osp_id, 1 AS att1, null as att2
    FROM att1
    GROUP BY estpt_id, sero_id, osp_id

    UNION 

    SELECT estpt_id, sero_id, osp_id, null AS att1, 2 AS att2
    FROM att1
    GROUP BY estpt_id, sero_id, osp_id
  )
)
SELECT 
   COALESCE(att1.value,att2.value) as value,
   base.osp_id,
   COALESCE(att1.stya_id,att2.stya_id) as stya_id,
   base.estpt_id, 
   COALESCE(att1.discount,att2.discount) as discount,
   eoax.discount, 
   base.sero_id 
FROM base
LEFT JOIN att1 ON base.estpt_id = att1.estpt_id and base.sero_id = att1.sero_id and base.osp_id and att1.osp_id and source = 1
LEFT JOIN att2 ON base.estpt_id = att2.estpt_id and base.sero_id = att2.sero_id and base.osp_id and att2.osp_id and source = 2
```

Comment: Thank you! This all should be used inside left outer join? And what does do left join here? :)

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by the left outer join -- you refused to show that code so I can't help you with it. @Viktor -- whatever it is a CTE does not work in a JOIN so I'd have to see that code to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

> If records exists with attr_number = 2, then i should get records only those records.
>   If records do not exists with attr_number = 2, then i should get records only where attr_number = 1.

Can this is solved using `RANK` on records fetched from the left outer join?

Simple demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=21f9cde30adce6dde639c0b6121023f9).

Comment: Not completely. I can't go outside `left outer join`, so i need to work inside it. So your option of solution wont work, heh. I had also an idea to use rank, but then i would need to find records by `osp_id` inside select, witch won't work, because `srv.osp_id` exists only ouside.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't help, but not sure I completely understand either :)
Based on your image, `osp_id` is present in the select (which technically is your subquery that you call `intrate`). Wouldn't it then be a case of applying a rank function inside `intrate` and then left outer join `intrate` with `srv`, `estpt`, `esero` etc.? Updated my demo to include another example

Comment: Yep, it presents in my select and then i call it in `intrate` and compare. This should stay as it is. I will check your second solution. Thanks.

Comment: Still, it wont work. I cant go outside, there should be no `where` statement after `intrate`. You forgot 1 thing, the `attr_number` is fictive column, so i cant just do 9 line and select that value from any of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you are able to use this filter

```
with test  as
   (select 1 id, 'ABC attr 1' description, 1 attr_number from dual union all
select 2 id, 'DEF attr 1' description, 1 attr_number from dual union all
select 2 id, 'DEF attr 2' description, 2 attr_number from dual union all
select 2 id, 'DEF attr 3' description, 3 attr_number from dual union all
select 3 id, 'GHI attr 3' description, 3 attr_number from dual
   )
   select *
   from test t1
   where attr_number = 2
   or ( attr_number = 1 and not exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.attr_number = 2 and t1.id = t2.id));
```